# Unmanaged Exports / Delphi / .NET 4 / Robert Giesecke

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I've successfully used Roberts [UnmanagedExportLibrary.zip](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) to call a .NET 2/3.5 assembly from Delphi 2007.

However when I recompile the C# assembly to target .NET 4 using VS2010 the call crashes with a stack overflow exception in ntdll.dll. (ntdll calling ntdll) after loading mscorlib/mscoreei.

Has anybody else got this to work when targeting .NET 4? - Robert's documentation seems to imply that this should work.

Great work by Robert by the way - very useful.

Thanks
Myles.

Comment: Maybe ask @RobertGiesecke himself? http://stackoverflow.com/users/35443/robert-giesecke

Comment: We've got a Delphi 2010 app calling a DLL compiled with .Net 4. Works fine. What code have you got that fails? Seem to recall I had to stop returning strings as function results. Only returned int values and any string passing was done via out parameters - or something like that.

Comment: Thanks very much for that info - yes the .NET function is returning a string. Now that I know it can work with .NET 4, I will go back and spend some more time on it.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are more tricky because you need to take more care over where the array is allocated and destroyed. The cleanest approach is always to allocate at the caller, pass the array to the callee to let it fill out the array. That approach would look like this in your context:

```
public struct Sample
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Name;
}

[DllExport]
public static int func(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=1)]
    Sample[] samples, 
    ref int len
)
{
    // len holds the length of the array on input
    // len is assigned the number of items that have been assigned values 
    // use the return value to indicate success or failure
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        samples[i].Name = "foo: " + i.ToString();
    return 0;
}
```

You need to specify that the array needs to be marshalled in the out direction. If you wanted values marshalled both ways then you would use `In, Out` instead of `Out`. You also need to use `MarshalAs` with `UnmanagedType.LPArray` to indicate how to marshal the array. And you do need to specify the size param so that the marshaller knows how many items to marshal back to the unmanaged code.

And then on the Delphi side you declare the function like this:

```
type
  TSample = record
    Name: WideString;
  end;
  PSample = ^TSample;

function func(samples: PSample; var len: Integer): Integer; stdcall; 
  external dllname;
```

Call it like this:

```
var
  samples: array of TSample;
  i, len: Integer;
....
len := 10;
SetLength(samples, len);
if func(PSample(samples), len)=0 then
  for i := 0 to len-1 do
    Writeln(samples[i].Name);
```

---

**Update**

As AlexS [discovered][1] (see comments below), passing the size param index by reference is only supported on .net 4. On earlier versions you need to pass the size param index by value.

The reason I chose to pass it by reference here is to allow for the following protocol:

1. The caller passes *in* a value indicating how large the array is.
2. The callee passes *out* a value indicating how many elements have been populated.

This works well on .net 4, but on earlier versions you would need to use an extra parameter for step 2.

Reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22507948/4339857