# How do I pass arrays of struct from .NET to Delphi using unmanaged export (Robert Giesecke)?

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I have just asked and obtained an answer to my question that was : "can't return custom type instance with unmanaged export (Robert Giesecke)" -> [can't return custom type instance with unmanaged export (Robert Giesecke)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503718/cant-return-custom-type-instance-with-unmanaged-export-robert-giesecke)
I wonder if (and how) it is possible to pass arrays of struct from .NET to Delphi using unmanaged export (Robert Giesecke):

- Returning arrays directly like

`[DllExport] public static void CreateSampleInstance(out Sample[] sample)`

- using array member in a returned struct

`[DllExport] public static void CreateSampleInstance(out Sample sample)`

and

```
`public struct Sample
{
   Other[] Others;
}`
```

My question here is how to write the Delphi side and what attribute to set in the .NET one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are more tricky because you need to take more care over where the array is allocated and destroyed. The cleanest approach is always to allocate at the caller, pass the array to the callee to let it fill out the array. That approach would look like this in your context:

```
public struct Sample
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Name;
}

[DllExport]
public static int func(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=1)]
    Sample[] samples, 
    ref int len
)
{
    // len holds the length of the array on input
    // len is assigned the number of items that have been assigned values 
    // use the return value to indicate success or failure
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        samples[i].Name = "foo: " + i.ToString();
    return 0;
}
```

You need to specify that the array needs to be marshalled in the out direction. If you wanted values marshalled both ways then you would use `In, Out` instead of `Out`. You also need to use `MarshalAs` with `UnmanagedType.LPArray` to indicate how to marshal the array. And you do need to specify the size param so that the marshaller knows how many items to marshal back to the unmanaged code.

And then on the Delphi side you declare the function like this:

```
type
  TSample = record
    Name: WideString;
  end;
  PSample = ^TSample;

function func(samples: PSample; var len: Integer): Integer; stdcall; 
  external dllname;
```

Call it like this:

```
var
  samples: array of TSample;
  i, len: Integer;
....
len := 10;
SetLength(samples, len);
if func(PSample(samples), len)=0 then
  for i := 0 to len-1 do
    Writeln(samples[i].Name);
```

---

**Update**

As AlexS [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628727/731183) (see comments below), passing the size param index by reference is only supported on .net 4. On earlier versions you need to pass the size param index by value.

The reason I chose to pass it by reference here is to allow for the following protocol:

1. The caller passes *in* a value indicating how large the array is.
2. The callee passes *out* a value indicating how many elements have been populated.

This works well on .net 4, but on earlier versions you would need to use an extra parameter for step 2.

Comment: Thank you ! I had to put a var before samples like that : `function (var samples: PSample; var len:Integer) : Integer; stdcall;`

Comment: sorry, but if I strictly use your recommandation I only get an empty array after calling my .NET function. If I put a ref keyword on the array parameter of my .NET function, it works ! btw I create the array  on delphi side, give it to .NET which fill it and return it back to delphi.

Comment: You should remove that `Array.Resize`. Let me just double check and test the code.

Comment: so I have removed the `Array.Resize(ref samples, len);` line but it stills raise an exception. The only way I managed to make it works is by having a var samples parameter in the delphi function, a ref samples parameter in the .NET function and a Array.Resize() in the .NET function.

Comment: No, there is a problem. I will work it out and update my answer.

Comment: That will teach me to answer on a topic that I am not fluent without double checking the code. I've tested the code in the updated answer now. It works and I believe this answer is not worthy of your accept.

Comment: Was a chronic mis-think on my part. I'm more used to standard pinvoke. This is reverse pinvoke. And of course this way round there's no way for the managed code which receives the array to know how many items to marshal. Thank you very much for staying with me and helping me put it right. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Congratulations! it works like a charm! Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi! I finally still have a weird behavior doing things like that : I SetLength the size of the delphi array to 50 but when I receive it on .NET side it is 341658 (it even seems to change at each call!). Can you explain that ?

Comment: Not without code. I'm sure the code in my answer is fine. My guess is that your Delphi code passes an unitialized local variable for the length param.

Comment: I am sorry it was my mistake. I added some parameters to my .NET function before the array and I did not change SizeParamIndex...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried your code, but I keep getting exceptions (D7 .Net3.5). The code of Guimcha (Array.Resize) works at the moment, but I'm concerned about memory leaks. Are you sure you didn't miss something or do I have to use .NET4 upwards?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626404/passing-array-of-struct-from-c-sharp-to-delphi). Maybe you can point me to the right direction.

Comment: This code only works for .NET >= 4.0. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24628727/731183).

Comment: I know this one is old post, but can you guys please rewrite the Delphi code in C++ too? I can't understand it and there is no good converter for it, thank you in advance.

Comment: What if I want to extend the struct with a simple integer property? Will it require a lot of changes? Tried to simple add in in C# and Delphi side, but it resulted in an array with unreadable data