# Passing array of struct from c# to delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I am using Robert Giesecke **Unmanaged Exports 1.2.6** in **VS2010** and my goal is to pass an array of structs from **c# (.NET 3.5)** to **delphi (D7)**.
I have to admit, that I'm not that familiar with delphi.

I've already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507681/how-do-i-pass-arrays-of-struct-from-net-to-delphi-using-unmanaged-export-rober), but the suggested answer didn't work for me:
When calling `func` in delphi the CPU-debugging-window opens and if I continue the app exits without exception and without the desired result.

Here is the code I tried:

**C# platform x86**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace ArrayTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public struct Sample
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string Name;
        }

        [DllExport]
        public static int func(
            [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
            Sample[] samples,
            ref int len
        )
        {
            // len holds the length of the array on input
            // len is assigned the number of items that have been assigned values 
            // use the return value to indicate success or failure
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                samples[i].Name = "foo: " + i.ToString();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Delphi7**

```
program DelphiApp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX;

type
  TSample = record
    Name: WideString;
  end;
  PSample = ^TSample;

function func(samples: PSample; var len: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  external 'ArrayTest.dll';

procedure Test2;
var
  samples: array of TSample;
  i, len: Integer;
begin
  len := 10;
  SetLength(samples, len);
  if func(PSample(samples), len)=0 then
    for i := 0 to len-1 do
      Writeln(samples[i].Name);
end;

begin
  Test2();
end.
```

As mentioned earlier, the debugger opens the CPU-Window and if I continue the app exits without exception or error message.
If I run it without dbugger, Windows tells me the app isn't working any more and the app closes.

What am I missing?

**Update**

Modified code:

```
[DllExport]
public static int func(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    Sample[] samples,
    ref int len
)
{
    Console.WriteLine("return 0");
    return 0;
}

procedure Test2;
var
  samples: array of TSample;
  i, len: Integer;
begin
  len := 10;
  SetLength(samples, len);
  if func(PSample(samples), len)=0 then
    for i := 0 to len-1 do
      Writeln('D7: ', i);
end;
```

Even if I don't access the array on either side, the behaviour still is the same.

Console-output: `return 0`

Comment: Run with the debugger. Sounds like load time link failure. If the link succeeds you'd be able to step into the program. The code does work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am able to step into the program and I am running the debugger. The debugger opens the CPU window on calling `func()`. The for-loop is not executed any more. Console-output inside the C#-function is done, thus the dll is linked and executed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What .NET, delphi and UnmanagedExport version are you using?

Comment: I'm not using anything now. That Q is from the past. I won't be able to look at this for a little while.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan FYI: I found the issue. It's about .NET-versions. See my answer below. Anyway thank's for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like I found the issue:

The code runs fine if .NET 4.0 or higher is used. If you use .NET 3.5 or lower the len-parameter has to be passed by value.

See MSDN-documentation [SizeParamIndex v3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex%28v=vs.90%29):

> The parameter containing the size must be an integer that is passed by value.

See MSDN-documentation [SizeParamIndex v4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex%28v=vs.100%29):

> When arrays are passed as C-style arrays, the marshaler cannot
>   determine the size of the array. Therefore, to pass an managed array
>   to an unmanaged function or method, you must provide two arguments:
>
> - The array, defined by reference or value.
> - The array size, defined by reference or value.

### Code working with .NET 3.5:

**C#**

```
[DllExport]
public static int func(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    Sample[] samples,
    int len,
    ref int outLen
)
{
    // len holds the length of the array on input
    // outLen is assigned the number of items that have been assigned values 
    // use the return value to indicates success and the required array size (>=0) or failure (<0)
    int requiredSize = 20;
    if (requiredSize < len)
    {
        len = requiredSize;
    }
    for (outLen = 0; outLen < len; outLen++)
    {
        samples[outLen].Name = "foo: " + outLen.ToString();
    }
    return requiredSize;
}
```

**Delphi7**

```
function func(samples: PSample; len: Integer; var outLen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  external 'ArrayTest.dll';

procedure Test2;
var
  samples: array of TSample;
  i, len: Integer;
begin
  len := 0;
  // query the required array size
  i := func(PSample(samples), len, len);
  if i>0 then
  begin
    len := i;
    SetLength(samples, len);
    if func(PSample(samples), len, len)>=0 then
      for i := 0 to len-1 do
        Writeln(samples[i].Name);
  end;
end;
```

### Conclusion:

The code posted in my question and posted by David Heffernan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22507948/731183) only works with .NET >= 4.0!
**If you have to use .NET <= 3.5 you must pass the arraysize by value and not by reference!**