# C# Dll library does not return output parameters value to a Delphi application

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I've written a Dll with C# with an exported function that save a file.

Here's the C# code

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;    

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [DllExport("Funcion", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void Funcion(IntPtr pDataIn, Int32 pSize, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int pArchivo)
        {
            byte[] documento = new byte[pSize];
            Marshal.Copy(pDataIn, documento, 0, pSize);
            File.WriteAllBytes("Document2.pdf", documento);            

            pArchivo = 25;
        }
    }    
}
```

In Delphi, I load the library and call the exported function and it works fine.

Here's the Delphi Code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lStream     : TMemoryStream;
  lArBytes      : array of Byte;
  lInDocSize : Integer;
  lHndle : THandle;

  Funcion : procedure(pDataIn : array of Byte;
                      pInSize : Integer;
                      var pDocumento : Integer
                      ); stdcall;
begin

  try
    lHndle := LoadLibrary('ClassLibrary1.dll');

    if (lHndle <> 0) then
    begin

      Funcion := GetProcAddress(lHndle, 'Funcion');

      if Assigned(Funcion) then
      begin
        try
          lStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

          lStream.LoadFromFile('Document1.PDF');
          lStream.Position := 0;

          SetLength(lArBytes, lStream.Size);

          lStream.Read(lArBytes[0], lStream.Size);

          lInDocSize := 0;
          Funcion(lArBytes, lStream.Size, lInDocSize);

          Label1.Caption := IntToStr(lInDocSize);

        except on E : Exception do
          begin
            RaiseLastOSError;
            ShowMessage(e.Message);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;

  finally
  end;

end;
```

I have an error with the output parameter, it is that always returns cero (0) value, not matter what value I assign to parameter, it always has cero value.

I've changing the parameter like this

```
out int pArchivo
```

and

```
ref int pArchivo
```

But when the function finish I get a memory exception.

With Marshal, function finish fine, without memory errors, but the output paramerter value is always cero (0).

```
[Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int pArchivo
```

I've read about this problem in this post in Stackoverflow

[Passing array of struct from c# to Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626404/passing-array-of-struct-from-c-sharp-to-delphi)

But in my case, it doesn't work

What I'm doing wrong?

I hope that you could help... thank you so much

Comment: out int pArchivo is correct. Use that. The other error is due to the open array not matching the c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Delphi side, a function parameter directly declared as `array of ...` is known as an ["open array"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters).  An "open array" gets passed by the compiler using **2** parameters - a pointer to the first array element, and the high index (not the length!) of the array.  This allows the calling code to pass either a static array or a dynamic array to the same parameter, and the compiler will pass the array data accordingly.

But, your .NET code is expecting only 1 parameter for the array - a raw pointer to the 1st array element.  That is why you are not getting your output value correctly.  Your `lStream.Size` parameter value gets passed where the .NET code expects the 3rd parameter to be, so the `Size` value gets misinterpreted as the memory address where the .NET code writes its output `pArchivo` value to, hence the memory error.  Which won't matter anyway since you are corrupting the call stack!  You end up pushing **4** parameter values onto the stack, and then `stdcall` on the .NET side pops off only **3** parameter values during stack cleanup when the function exits.

You need to change the declaration of your `Funcion` variable, either by:

- **keeping the `pDataIn` parameter declared as `array of Byte`, but removing the explicit `pInSize` parameter**. Let the compiler pass it implicitly:

  ```
  Funcion : procedure(pDataIn : array of Byte;
                      //pInSize : Integer;
                      var pDocumento : Integer
                      ); stdcall;
  ```

  You will then have to change the call of `Funcion()` to allocate +1 more byte for the `lArBytes` array so the compiler passes the correct size value to the `pSize` parameter:

  ```
  SetLength(lArBytes, lStream.Size+1); // <-- +1 here!
  lStream.Read(PByte(lArBytes)^, High(lArBytes)); // <-- no +1 here!
  ...
  Funcion(lArBytes{, High(lArBytes)}, lInDocSize);
  ```

  Needless to say, this is not intuitive, though it *should* work since the behavior of open arrays is well-known, though it is a private implementation detail of the Delphi compiler.
- **using `PByte` (or just `Pointer`) instead of `array of Byte`**:

  ```
  Funcion : procedure(pDataIn : PByte; // <-- here
                      pInSize : Integer;
                      var pDocumento : Integer
                      ); stdcall;
  ```

  You will then have to change the call of `Funcion()` to pass a pointer to the 1st array element, and pass the array length explicitly:

  ```
  SetLength(lArBytes, lStream.Size); // <-- no +1 here!
  lStream.Read(PByte(lArBytes)^, Length(lArBytes)); // <-- or here!
  ...
  Funcion(@lArBytes[0]{or: PByte(lArBytes)}, Length(lArBytes), lInDocSize);
  ```

  This is more intuitive, and closer to what the .NET code is expecting.

Alternatively, I suggest you simply get rid of your `lArBytes` variable altogether.  You don't actually need it.  Since the .NET code is expecting a raw pointer to the byte data, simply pass your `TMemoryStream` data directly:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lStream    : TMemoryStream;
  lInDocSize : Integer;
  lHndle : THandle;

  Funcion : procedure(pDataIn : Pointer;
                      pInSize : Integer;
                      var pDocumento : Integer
                      ); stdcall;
begin

  lHndle := LoadLibrary('ClassLibrary1.dll');
  if (lHndle <> 0) then
  try
    Funcion := GetProcAddress(lHndle, 'Funcion');
    if Assigned(Funcion) then
    begin
      lInDocSize := 0;

      lStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        lStream.LoadFromFile('Document1.PDF');
        Funcion(lStream.Memory, lStream.Size, lInDocSize);
      finally
        lStream.Free;
      end;

      Label1.Caption := IntToStr(lInDocSize);
    end;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(lHndle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy, I have tried with all your suggested changes and all of them works so fine. I've selected the last alternative, because it's the most easy way to do all that I need. 

Again, thanks for your help and your time!!!