# Return array of String in C# and get delphi [Interop]

Tags: c#, delphi, interop, delphi-7, com-interop

Follow this tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507681/how-do-i-pass-arrays-of-struct-from-net-to-delphi-using-unmanaged-export-rober) but no success. Returning memory address error.

I'm trying to like this, not me the memory error, but returns nulls

Code Delphi:

```
interface
   procedure getValores(samples: array of string); stdcall; external 'myDll.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
        vet :array[0..400] of string;
    begin
      getValues(vet);
      Layout('',vet);
    end;

    end.
```

Code of C#

```
        [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static void getValores(
            [Out]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,
             ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst=400)]
            String[] test
            )
        {
            if (test == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("null");
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Recive" + test.Length);

            for(int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
                test[i] = "test";

            return;
         }
```

someone has gone through this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Lots of ways. This code cannot work. Arrays and strings in Delphi are not Interpol safe. Your code won't even work if it was pure Delphi because you pass the array by value. You could encode the list as JASON for example. Or you could return one string at a time.

Comment: Or you could simply do what the answer at the question you linked to recommends. Quite why you didn't follow the advice there and made up your own code is beyond me.

Comment: Return a string at a time is a good idea. I will test tomorrow. Tks

Comment: I was almost all day trying to create structure and pass the rolled stack overflow but did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would break the problem down into 3 parts.

1. Get the calling conventions sorted out.  Stdcall and cdecl are mutually exclusive calling conventions.  You need to be absolutely sure of calling convention of the .dll, and then adjust your application code to match.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions
2. Make a simple test procedure that takes only one string (not an array).  You will need to make sure of the character set (Ansi vs. Unicode), and string length determination (BStr vs. LPStr).
3. Once these two issues are handled, then deal with the original array
   argument.

Comment: How to solve item 3 is the real problem. Please tell us how to do that, or this isn't an answer.