# How can I pass string array from C# to Delphi dll?

Tags: c#, arrays, delphi

I need to pass open array of strings from C# to Delphi dll. Sets the length of array in delphi and return it back to C#.
Are they any ways?

For the beginning I'm trying this code in C#:

```
public struct TStrSample
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Name;
}

[DllImport(@"EPConvs.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void PopulateStrArray([In, Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] TStrSample[] arr,
                                           ref int len);


[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void hcTable(SqlBytes blob)
{
    TStrSample[] arr = new TStrSample[10];
    int len = arr.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        arr[i].Name = i.ToString();
    }
    PopulateStrArray(arr, ref len);
}
```

Delphi part:

```
type
  TStrSample = record
    Name: WideString;
  end;
  PStrSample = ^TStrSample;

procedure PopulateStrArray(arr: PStrSample; var len: Integer); stdcall;
var
  i: Integer;
  returnArray: array of TStrSample;
begin
  returnArray := @arr;
  for i := 0 to Len-1 do
    returnArray[i].Name := 'YES = ' + IntToStr(i);
end;
```

But it does not work. What is wrong?

Comment: You aren't passing a Delphi dynamic array but that's what your Delphi code assumes. Also which way does the data flow. You appear to send it in both directions but both recipients ignore what is sent.

Comment: Personally I'd use pointer arithmetic to access the array elements. The Delphi type unsafe @ operator is not helping you. Enable the typed address option. Then remove the dynamic array. Then access using pointer arithmetic. Oh, there are no open arrays here either.

Comment: > Personally I'd use pointer arithmetic to access the array elements.

Could you write an example how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm new to C #, but I need to fill an array in Delphi and pass this array back into C #.

Comment: Use pointer arithmetic. Read about that. Do you know about pointers. Why have me write your code when you can read the docs.

Comment: I took this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507681/how-do-i-pass-arrays-of-struct-from-net-to-delphi-using-unmanaged-export-rober as an example, But I can not understand what I did wrong.

Comment: That example goes in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed Delphi code and now it's working. Thanks to ***David Heffernan***.

```
type
  TStrSample = record
    Name: WideString;
  end;
  PStrSample = ^TStrSample;

procedure PopulateStrArray(arr: PStrSample; var len: Integer); stdcall;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to len - 1 do
  begin
    arr^.Name := 'YES = ' + IntToStr(i);
    Inc(arr);
  end;
end;
```

**Is there some possibility to pass an open array to Delphi?**